# How to perform this insert into PostgreSQL using MySQL data?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database-migration

I'm in the processing of moving over a mysql database to a postgres database. I have read all of the articles presented [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL), as well as reading over some of the solutions presented [on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385002/the-easiest-way-to-migrate-a-django-project-from-mysql-to-postgresql) The tools recommended don't seem to work for me. Both databases were generated by Django's syncdb, although the postgres db is more or less empty at the moment. I tried to migrate the tables over using Django's built in dumpdata / loaddata functions and its serializers, but it doesn't seem to like a lot of my tables, leading me to believe that writing a manual solution might be best in this case. I have code to verify that the column headers are the same for each table in the database and that the matching tables exist- that works fine. I was thinking it would be best to just grab the mysql data row by row and then insert it into the respective postgres table row by row (I'm not concerned with speed atm). The one thing is, I don't know what's the proper way to construct the insert statement. I have something like:

```
table_name = retrieve_table()
column_headers = get_headers(table_name) #can return a tuple or a list
postgres_cursor = postgres_con.cursor()
rows = mysql_cursor.fetchall()      
for row in rows: #row is a tuple
   postgres_cursor.execute(????)
```

Where ??? would be the insert statement. I just don't know what the proper way is to construct it. I have the table name that I would like to insert into as a string, I have the column headers that I can treat as a list, tuple, or string, and I have the respective values that I'd like to insert. What would be the recommended way to construct the statement? I have read the documentation on [psycopg's documentation page](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) and I didn't quite see the way that would satisfy my needs. I don't know (or think) this is the entirely correct way to properly migrate, so if someone could steer me in the correct way or offer any advice I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't the tools recommended work for you? It seems extremely inefficient to go through Django and/or psycopg to transfer the data over-- what's wrong with the more direct MySQL-to-Postgres routes that are detailed extensively at the links you posted above?

Comment: psycopg's docs are only applicable when you're interacting with Python code. When you get to the point of running `execute` you're dealing with straight SQL, so refer to the PostgreSQL docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/dml-insert.html.